# Refreshing Authentication token for Google Calendar API with Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, google-calendar-api

We are prototyping on a Raspberry Pi using the Google Calendar API.

Each user of this service will connect his or her own calendar to the Raspberry Pi and use the calendar information.

The Raspberry Pi we are using does not have a keyboard or display connected to it.

We are planning to connect a smartphone to the Raspberry Pi and have it set up a calendar, but we are using SSH to temporarily complete the authentication process.

We were able to retrieve the calendar information by following the steps below.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

But after about two weeks, an authentication error occurred.
It may depend on the expiration date of the refresh token.
Authentication once every two weeks is very annoying to customers.
Can we get around this?

We found out about Delegating domain-wide authority.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority

Does this solve our problem?
Can this be used to display the Calendar for domain-independent email addresses?
For example, if we delegate to admin@example.com can we get the Calendar information associated with example@gmail.com?

We have already been struggling with this for months.
Please give us any advice you can.

Add: Our code is as shown in the sample, but we will describe it here.

```
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            '/home/pi/credentials.json', SCOPES)
// --- Try Kelo's advice ------------------------
        flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
        flow.params['include_granted_scopes'] = 'true'
// --- Try Kelo's advice ------------------------
        creds = flow.run_console()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('/home/pi/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

If we use the wizard, we will see this warning.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code on each of the Raspberry Pis?

Comment: You have created two questions on Stackoverflow for this topic. You cannot achieve your goal of offline access to user data long term. Google requires users to reauthenticate periodically. If you are accessing user's data (aka sensitive scopes and restricted scopes), your application may require a third-party security assessment which has a cost between $15K and $75K (estimate). https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#sec-assess https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy#additional-requirements-for-specific-api-scopes

Comment: @iansedano Sorry. We overlooked this comment. We had noted it in the problem statement before the change. Our code is this.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Google API and direct access

Whenever you access **user data**, the user will need to authorize that, there is no way to go around this fact. You will always require a UI with the ability to "log in" or pass in a token. At the moment you are doing it via SSH, which is fine.

One part of your question is addressed towards whether you can get permanent access to the Google APIs from a device that does not have a interactive UI, and the answer is unfortunately, no, you cannot. Assuming your display is only able to give information, and not able to log-in to Google, then you'll need to do it via SSH or another method.

### Service Accounts and non UI methods

Another question of yours is about whether Service accounts will work for your purposes. Unfortunately the answer is also no. Service accounts are for Workspace domains (people in the same organization) which I understand is not your case.

### [Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

I understand that this is an IoT device and **not** a web server. However, there is a type of access called the "Offline" type. This is made available by Google to Web Server *type* applications.

[image]

Which is found when creating the credentials.

To be clear, I do *not* think this is a good solution for you. It would be possible, but not for people without a lot of tech knowledge, as each user would have to manage the Pi-as-server.

This is what a lot of people do with their IoT devices. Then they can "visit" the Pi as a web-page to give authorization and then it is granted the "Offline" type of access, and so, the authentication lasts longer. The Pi-as-server, usually only ever serves one web-page, to one person, usually on the local network. You can call it an IoT device or a web-server, in the end it serves the same function.

### Managing IoT Devices

I am not an expert in this field, but I understand that there are services designed for IoT devices, such as:

> https://cloud.google.com/iot-core/

Essentially to manage IoT devices you can set up something like this:

[image]

The key part being the bit in the middle that will manage the user's login information and access tokens. This will essentially be the "server" part that has "offline" access. Then this will query the Calendar API for the information and send it to the appropriate IoT device for that user.

This of course means keeping a database with the user info, access token, and which Raspberry Pi should be updated.

There are also PubSub services that act as a way to send messages between devices:

> https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/

#### *Please note:* this does not mean that you have to manage the calendar information, all you need to do is to manage the logins, tokens and *communication* between the Calendar API and the Raspberry Pis.

### Why can you do it on Android?

These types of applications work on android because you are **logged in** in a web-UI environment. Since you have already authorized your device, you can authorize apps through your device. Since you are not logged in with your Raspberry Pi, *and* you are in a CLI envionment you need to refresh the tokens.

### Disclaimer

There *may* be a way to do what you want easily, but I don't know it. If you find one, please add your own answer, I would be happy to read about it as I also have Raspberry Pis and this would be very interesting to me!

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation. But we also do not fully understand your explanation. We will take some more time to read your explanation.

Comment: We have read your text many times and tried to understand it. But you are talking about a different system than ours. We said Raspberry Pi and you mistook it for a server application. Let's consider the example of an Android device.

In this example, we will develop an application for Android. The Android application we develop will run on each of our customers' smartphones. Our application will use the Google Calendar API to retrieve the calendar information of each customer and display it on their smartphone. You can replace this smartphone with a Raspberry Pi to understand our system.

Comment: Also, we don't understand why you are so concerned with the way things are displayed. It is an important aspect of our service that we do not want to share. But you can imagine a Raspberry Pi with a small LCD. On that LCD, calendar information is displayed like a to-do list.

Comment: The way you suggested looks like we would have to collect their calendar information to our server and manage it ourselves.

We are not interested in their calendar information. We don't want to take such a risk.

Our customers don't want to provide us with their calendar information, they just want to display it on their IoT devices.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my answer to clarify your questions. I did not mistake your Raspberry Pi for a server, I am just saying that it is a possible solution, and it is the only solution that allows the "offline access". I was not suggesting for you to manage the calendar information, only to manage _access_ to the calendar API.

Comment: We don't even know why you are concerned about going offline. We have a Raspberry Pi connected via Wi-Fi. We're not using it offline. After all, you've misunderstood our system.

Comment: Its just the name of the type of access, it refers to the fact that the user is not present. Not that you are connected to the internet.

Comment: Why do you think the Raspberry Pi is not available in the same way as Android? Where is that documented? Can you post a link?

Comment: It is, but you would need to have a User Interface like a browser, and you say that you only have a simple display and have to access via SSH. If you can get the user to log in to the raspberry pi then it may be possible

Comment: Maybe this link will help you more https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device

Comment: Thank you. We had already read this. Since we are unlikely to get any more new information, we should end the question.

Comment: We are still trying to understand your advice without giving up. But we still don't understand the notes you have written in bold. What exactly is this sentence about? Can you provide a link to Google's documentation on this? Are you asking me to transfer the token that links Google Calendar to our service on the server to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: We had already tried the steps in the URL you suggested, but there is no calendar marked in the scope. Is this just outdated documentation? Or will Google not let us? It's working as expected so far, but we're afraid it's an unforgivable action.